# difference between 2 objects/arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 objects, which are associated arrays from PHP in JSON. They have an structure  like that´:

```
[object]
    ["green"]
         ['value1']=integer
         ['value1']=array...
    ["blue"]
         ['value1']=integer
         ['value1']=array...
    [...]
```

The 1st Version of this object is loaded from webserver periodically using JSON.
By receiving this new JSON string from webserver, the current object moved to the variable "oldObj" while the new data stored into the variable "newObj".
It could be possible, that the new object will have less elements than the old object, like this:

```
[newObj]
    ["green"]
         ['value1']=integer
         ['value1']=array...
```

As you can see: "blue" is missing.

Now i need this elements which are part of the old Object / that means: which are missing at the new object (at this example: element "blue")

I tried the following, but without any success:

```
[...]
    var newObj=data;
    $.each (oldObj,function(i,n)
            {if (newObj.i.length<1) {alert('missing: '+i);}
            }
         );//end foreach
```

Error message: "newObj.i is undefined"

Comment: Should be `newObj[i]` but that won't help you either. Objects don't have a "length" like arrays do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doing a "Diff" on an Associative Array in javascript / jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558800/doing-a-diff-on-an-associative-array-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: This might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200562/difference-in-json-objects-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: @Felix Kling i searched trough SO for an answer, but i didn't found your link. Thank you - i will check it.

Comment: @Felix Kling @Neeraj +1 - those links helps me a lot to find an solution --- in combination with the answer from wong2. Thanks at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I think newObj or oldObj can be wrote as:

```
var newObj = {
    "green": [
        integer,
        [array]
    ],
    "blue": [
        integer,
        [array]
    ]
};
```

Is it right?

You could use :

```
for(p in Obj){
    if(Obj.hasOwnProperty(p)){
        // do something with p
    }
}
```

to loop through the Obj's properties.

Comment: shouldn't it be for(p in oldObj){
    if(newObj.hasOwnPropery(p)){
        // do something with p
    } ....?
}

Comment: @Bndr of course you could do that, I'm just suggesting the general way to loop an object's properties.