# comparing json submitted array and sql returned array and printing difference in text file

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, array-difference

I am submitting a javascript array to another php page via ajax which runs a query and returns another array. Then i would like to compare these two arrays and print the difference in a text file. The code give below is creating a text file with no data in it.

Here is the code

```
 $('#tabletomodify').on('change','.street', 
        function (event) 
        {
                event.preventDefault();             
            var row=( $(this).closest('tr').prop('rowIndex') );
            var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
                var valueSelected = this.value;
            var ideSelected= this.id;               
            var values = '[';               
            values+=valueSelected+",";              
            for ($i=3;$i<row;$i++)
            {
                var dv="selectcity"+$i;
                var dv1=document.getElementById(dv).value;
                var sl="street"+$i;
                var sl1=document.getElementById(sl).value;
                var po="building"+$i;
                var po1=document.getElementById(po).value;
                var concat=dv1+sl1+po1;                 
                values+=''+concat+',';                  
            }
            values = values.substring(0,values.length-1);               
            values += ']';                              
            $.ajax({
             url: "get_buildings.php",
                 type: 'POST',               
                 data:  {data: values} ,
                 success: function(){
                alert("Success!")
                }
            });
```

the value sent to the get_buildings.php is

```
[newyork::roosevelt st,springfieldevergreen terraceno42,quahogspooner streetno43]
```

Php code get_buildings.php:-

```
    $a1='newyork::roosevelt st';
    $sl= explode("::",$a1);
    $a=$sl[1];

    $connection_buildings= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'DETAILS') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
    $sql_query_3 = "select buildings from $a";
    $result_query_3=mysqli_query($connection_buildings,$sql_query_3) or die ("check it");

    $options=array();
    while ($row = $result_query_3->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
      $name = $row['buildings']; 
      $val=$a.$sl[0].$name;  
       array_push($options,$val);
    }

    $result = array_diff($_POST['data'], $options);
    $fp = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);
    mysqli_close($connection_buildings);
```

Comment: If you're sending `[newyork::roosevelt st,springfieldevergreen terraceno42,quahogspooner streetno43]` like you say, that isn't valid JSON.  Also, your question wouldn't be clear even if you were sending valid JSON.  What is your definition of "different" between two arrays?  Is it based on keys?  Is it based strictly on values?  You don't show what your SQL array looks like.

Comment: this is what i meant by array difference [http://is2.php.net/array_diff] i.e strictly based on values. here is my sql array:-                                                    Array ( [0] =>springfieldevergreen terraceno42,[1] =>quahogspooner streetno43)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doing a "Diff" on an Associative Array in javascript / jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558800/doing-a-diff-on-an-associative-array-in-javascript-jquery)